# QueryingSolr : getRequestHandler returns result but not selectHandler

Tags: solr

I have id field in solr that uniquely identifies a solr document

When querying solr using getHandler :
solr/{collection}/get?id=p_1266762970&fl=*

Result: 
"doc":
  {
    "lastIndexed":"2014-12-25T09:48:56.509Z",
    "id":"1266762970",
    "solrId":"p_1266762970",
 .....
  }

But when querying using solr admin - selectHandler - no documents are returned.

Solr query looks like:
solr/{collection}/select?q=*:*&fq=solrId:p_1266762970
solr/{collection}/select?q=*:*&fq=id:1266762970

I tried doing a hard commit and it returned successfully but still the same results

I have other documents in solr as well that shows up correct results.This issue exist for some of the ids (8 out of 2.3 million) only.

Updated: UniqueKey is

```
<uniqueKey>solrId</uniqueKey>
```

Comment: Can you update your query to NOT be URL escaped just to understand better what's going on. Also, what's your uniqueId field definition in the schema.xml. You see to have two different id fields.

Comment: @Alexandre Rafalovitch:Updated the post

Comment: Something still not right there (* : *) for the query I assume? And why two queries?

solr/{collection}/select?q=:&fq=solrId:p_1266762970 

solr/{collection}/select?q=:&fq=id:1266762970